# General questions on Xcode iOS 7 Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm following the Stanford Developing iOS 7 course 2013 2014 on iTunes U (just for your info) and I'm having some general questions on the Objective C language. Thanks for your help!

Question 01
This is what I understood about @synthesize:
With the newest versions of Xcode there is no need to perform @synthesize for declaring a setter or a getter. It is done automatically for the programmer if the getter and setter is kept at default. However I have been taught I need to declare the synthesize when overrides BOTH the getter and the setter.
My question is: why only when BOTH are being overriden? It should make more sense to me you would need to declare the synthesize already when only one needs to be overridden?

Question 02

```
- (void)addCard:(Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop;
- (void)addCard:(Card *)card;
```

Are 2 different public methods used in the course I'm following. 
Question: Am I required to state these two as 2 individual methods. Couldn't I just use the first one, whilst specifying 2 different blocks of code to perform, by an IF ELSE clausule whether the BOOL is YES or NO? Wouldn't that be exactly the same outcome?

Question 03

Having a rather simple program with just a single view, I noticed I do not need to publicly specify any methods in my viewcontroller.h. I reckon this only would be needed if your program is more complex and contains several MVC where the controllers would need to "speak" to each other. Is this a right assumption to make, generally speaking, when making a proper MVC based program?

I thank you for your time and effort. Excuse me if my questions seem basic or do not make complete sense. I'm on the iOS learning path stage 1, with little OOP experience.

Comment: It's best to ask just one question per post. There's no charge for making multiple posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:**

You are right about this. If you override the getter and setter then you need to @synthesize the property. I'll have to have a further look for why though.

**Question 2:**

Yes, you could just have the first method. However, the second method is there as a convenience and would normally contain code something like this...

```
- (void)addCard:(Card *)card
{
    [self addCard:card atTop:YES];
}
```

Then the designated method would do something like...

```
- (void)addCard:(Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop
{
    if (atTop) {
        // something to add card to top.
    } else {
        // something to add card at bottom.
    }
}
```

i.e. it just routes the method call to the "designated" method but uses a default value for the BOOL.

**Question 3:**

The .h file is there as an interface file. It would be similar to a set of web services on a server. The class can do all sorts of stuff internally but it only needs to declare stuff in the .h interface file if something needs to access them externally.

For instance, you might have a class called `Car`. It might have a button called `accelerator` that would access an internal method and increase the speed. None of this needs to be exposed to external classes.

However, the same car might have a property called `colour` or a method called `addFuel`. These would need to be available externally so the user can see the colour and add fuel. These both need to go in the .h file.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand number 1; if you've provided both getter and setter implementations, then what's left to synthesize?

Comment: @trojanfoe I think synthesize links the property to an ivar too. That's whats left to synthesize.

Comment: @Thedude But then there is no need as the getter/setter will use the correct instance variable explicitly.

Comment: @trojanfoe If you write both methods and don't write the synthesize line, _propertyName won't be an ivar. If you declare the ivar in the interface section too, I think then you're right, there's really nothing left to synthesize.

Comment: @Thedude I think you're right, but then I'd argue that it's perhaps better to explicitly declare the instance variable.

Comment: @trojanfoe that's debatable, but I find `@synthesize myVar;` shorter and more readable than eg. `NSArray *_myVar;`, and with the former, you don't have to redeclare the type of the property.

Comment: @trojanfoe If you declare the instance variable there's no direct link between it and the property. You have to check the setter and getter code to see the relation. Using `@synthesize property = ivar;` explicitly declares a relation between them both. For that reason I prefer the second option.

Comment: @Thedude However if you do that the custom getter/setter could easily use a different instance variable.  The `@synthesize property = ivar;` is no guarantee that `ivar` is actually being used by the getter/setter of `property`.

Comment: Is it to do with the memory management settings on the property? If you synthesize the iVar then it will pick up ARC memory management from the property (i.e. strong, weak, copy, assign, etc...) but with iVar you have an unrelated ivar.

Comment: @trojanfoe You convinced me.

Comment: @Fogmeister I don't think there is a "correct way" to do this when you want a custom getter/setter method.  Actually, even though I've been arguing against it, I think I like the idea of still using `@property` as it conveys more information about the instance variable than an explicit declaration does.  Therefore I think I would prefer to declare the `@property`, the `@synthesize property = _ivar` **and** still provide a custom getter/setter.  I don't think memory management has anything to do with it as you can set those attributes on the instance variable declaration just as easily.

Comment: @Thedude I think I've convinced myself otherwise.  I am fickle, but it's good to *chew the fat* :)

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1:  I have been taught I need to declare the synthesize when
>   overrides BOTH the getter and the setter. My question is: why only
>   when BOTH are being overriden? It should make more sense to me you
>   would need to declare the synthesize already when only one needs to be
>   overridden?

Once you use `@synthesize` you are using the setter/getter provided by the compiler. If you create your setter/getter without `synthesize` then you need to write both the methods, if you have `readwrite` property.

---

> Question 2: Am I required to state these two as 2 individual methods.
>   Couldn't I just use the first one, whilst specifying 2 different
>   blocks of code to perform, by an IF ELSE clausule whether the BOOL is
>   YES or NO? Wouldn't that be exactly the same outcome?

Yes it is good to have two different methods. As these two vary on the parameters and the caller will know what is happening inside the method. If you wish to put if-else, for this you will require an ivar or a global value to check, but if you pass the BOOL no need for it.

---

> Question 3: Having a rather simple program with just a single view, I noticed I do
>   not need to publicly specify any methods in my viewcontroller.h. I
>   reckon this only would be needed if your program is more complex and
>   contains several MVC where the controllers would need to "speak" to
>   each other. Is this a right assumption to make, generally speaking,
>   when making a proper MVC based program?

Even though you don't have any complex but always follow the architecture of MVC.

The controller in iOS programming usually refers to the view controllers. Think of a view controller as a bridge between the model and your views. This controller interprets what is happening on one side and uses that information to alter the other side as needed. For instance, if the user changes some field in a view, the controller makes sure the model changes in response. And if the model gets new data, the controller tells the view to reflect it.

Answer (score -1):

**Question 01**

(*edited*) You need `@synthesize` to tell the compiler to create the ivar (eg. `_myString`) for you. You could also declare the ivar manually.

**Question 02**

You could just declare the first one yes. In fact the second one just a shorthand method, providing a default value for `atTop`. In most cases, you would implement the method exactly as you explained:

```
- (void)addCard:(Card *)card atTop:(BOOL)atTop {
    if (atTop) {
        // atTop == YES
    }
    else {
        // atTop == NO
    }
}

- (void)addCard:(Card *)card {
    [self addCard:card atTop:YES]; // or atTop:NO, depending of the default value you want to use
}
```

**Question 03**

Again, yes. Your view controllers should expose as little properties and methods as possible, and make public only things that should be available for the rest of the application to use. So in the case of the single VC / single view program, having an empty VC interface is normal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What about a simple @synthesize suit = _suit; for private use? Is this a wrong programming method which would be programmed alternatively?

Comment: @Fogmeister, yep you're right, guess I'm not implementing the getter *and* setter of my properties too often. I fixed the answer.

Comment: So when there is only a getter OR a setter which is being overriden from the default automatic ones, you do not need the @synthesize line? For example, I just let Xcode compiler do all the getters and setters automatically. However, I want to adjust the Name of the getter to something more readable in code. In that case I will not need the synthesize line, correct? When I want to change both the getter and setter Names, I do need the synthesize line?

Comment: @N34X that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Fogmeister. I read through the comments above. But it still does not make complete sense to as why the line of synthesize is not required when there is only one of both overriden?

Comment: @N34X because Clang does it for you : http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objective-c-autosynthesis-of-properties. However, if you implement the getter AND the setter, Clang assumes that you will not need an ivar, or if you do, you will declare it explicitly. Hope it makes sense.